# Does itemprop="url" refer to the page where the code is added?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I would like to add Microdata for my social profiles. I read that I could to add it in this way:

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">   
 <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.your-company-site.com">
 <a itemprop="sameAs" href="http://www.facebook.com/your-company">FB</a>  
 <a itemprop="sameAs" href="http://www.twitter.com/YourCompany">Twitter</a>
</span>
```

But I have a bid doubt about

```
<link itemprop="url" href="???????????">
```

I have my social button (with links to social profiles) in homepage but also in the other pages of my website. So this Microdata would always be present. Therefore it is a mistake to have always:

```
 <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.homepage.com">
```

so always the same link (homepage), where social button (and Microdata) there will be also in other pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`url` property](http://schema.org/url) of an `Organization` is for providing the organization’s URL. This is typically the homepage of the organization’s website.

So it is correct to always have the same `url` value wherever you provide the `Organization` item. In the same way, the organization’s [`name`](http://schema.org/name), [`address`](http://schema.org/address) etc. would always be the same, too.

It is not required to provide structured data under this `url`, but it would of course make sense to do so.

Comment: i have another only one doubt.... Is right to use "Organitazation" in my case that is a website about science and nature ??? and in the page i can use other type of microdata for other things (for example breadcrumbs) ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user3162975: Yes, you can and should markup multiple entities (this is, for example, [what Google recommends](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23612602/1591669)). To decide if it’s right to use `Organization` in your case can’t be answered without knowing more about your case. If the page is related to an organization (e.g., the organization is the author of the page, or the page is about that organization, or the organization is mentioned, or it’s the organization’s website, etc.), it’s probably appropriate to use `Organization`.

Comment: @user3162975: Schema.org is just a way to make the content (which you have on your pages, ideally but not necessarily visible for human visitors) machine-understandable. So whatever content you have, it’s appropriate to use Schema.org to represent it (if Schema.org offers suitable types).

Comment: Yes i write the page and i'm the website (not an author... For example i will use a rel=publisher for google and not rel=author).. Now do you think that i should to use "Organizazion" ? You are very kind, thanks a lot.  (Ahh anorher thing :D but this markup is only for machine or made a type of rich snippet?)

Comment: @user3162975: With the details you provided, it’s not clear if using `Organization` is appropriate … do you have content about an organization / is the website from an organization? If yes, it’s obviously appropriate to use `Organization`; if not, not. -- Schema.org markup is for anyone interested in it; this would be primarily bots, of course (e.g., from search engines). Some bots might do something with this markup (in the case of search engines, they might display Rich Snippets).

Comment: Well no ... I am not an organization .. so instead that entities could use ? 
It is a simple website ...(mapsism.com)

Comment: @user3162975:Sorry, I can’t help with this (the comments on this question should focus on the question’s topic); and I don’t understand most of your content ;-) Schema.org has [many types](http://schema.org/docs/schemas.html): if you say something about a person (which could be you), use `Person`; if you have an article, use `Article`; if you have a map, use `Map`; etc. And of course each page could be a `WebPage`, and you could have a `WebSite` entity that represents your whole website.

Comment: Last thing... If i use another type, the example in my post is the same but i must to change only the url of schema.org of itemtype in the span? Right? Thank a lot for all :)

Comment: @user3162975: Yes, but note that it also has to make sense to use these properties for whichever type you choose. For example, providing the homepage URL, the Twitter URL and the Facebook URL might make sense for a `Person` (if this is the person’s website, the person’s Twitter, and the person’s Facebook), but not for an `Article`.

Comment: hmm....yes i understand...well the problem in my case is understand which type use... maybe as you suggest "WebSite" ? ( forgive me, I understand that I am stressing all these messages ... but I want to understand how to best use this markup ... I'm Italian and in my language there is nothing that describes all types of schema.org: /)