# 'Things' per page for Google Rich Snippets

Tags: seo, schema.org, rich-snippets, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

Our home page has JSON-LD for our organization. Should our product pages have that chunk of code as well?

If Google crawls one of our product pages and finds `@type:` `Organization` and `@type:` `Product`, will it have trouble determining the nature of that particular page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s say you want to convey that your [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) is the  [`manufacturer`](http://schema.org/manufacturer) of the [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product):

Inside of the `Product` node, you could either provide the full `Organization` node as value, or you could provide the URI of the `Organization` as value, which gets specified with `@id` in the `Organization` node ([see an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34776122/1591669)).

Referencing the identifier has the advantage that you don’t have to repeat yourself, but the disadvantage that it’s perhaps more work for the consumer (they might not support it).

Google doesn’t explicitly mention in their [Rich Snippets documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/) if they follow URIs and take the referenced node into consideration, while embedding nodes seems to be supported according to their examples and their [SDTT](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/).

> If Google crawls one of our product pages and finds `@type:` `Organization` and `@type:` `Product`, will it have trouble determining the nature of that particular page?

Google even [recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23612602/1591669) to markup (or in case of JSON-LD, provide data for) *all* entities on a page.

Also note that Schema.org offers a property that allows to denote which entity is the primary one (e.g., `Product` on a product page, `Organization` on the homepage): [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity)/[`mainEntityOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) (see my [answer with more details](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/87982/17633)).